# Base64 Encoding is different in Java and C# how to get same?

Tags: c#, java, encoding, base64, signed

in C#:

```
encryptionKey="Wb2bLNGXABcl4Lz........AxqA5Xhsoqi7w52RKA=";

var key = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptionKey);

key value={89,189,155,44,209,151,0,23,37,224,188,250,186,104,35,70,250,81,212,12,106,3,149,225,178,138,162,239,14,118,68,160}
```

in java:

```
byte[] key= Base64.decodeBase64(encryptionKey);

key={89,-67,-101,44,-47,-105,0,23,37,-32,-68,-6,-70,104,-21,70,-6,81,-44,12,106,3,-107,-31,-78,-118,-94,-17,14,118,68,-96};
```

key value is different in Java and C#. how to get same value in Java?

Comment: i am looking for relevant code in java for same output.

Comment: They *are* they same output. Java's displaying signed bytes, C# isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same. In the first case bytes are unsigned and Java bytes are signed. What we see in array is different interpretation of the same value, eg 189 and -67 = 0xBD

byte b = (byte) 189;

now b = -67

Comment: thanks Evgeniv Dorofeev